# Way to remove BOM from Blob for Apps Script E-Mail Attachment

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using *Google Apps Script* to send an e-mail from within Google Sheets. I send a small CSV file, and it actually does work. But, when I open the attachment in Microsoft Excel, cell A1 has a couple of strange characters in it. When I open in a text editor, it looks fine.

I'm working on a Mac, so I used the hex editor in Xcode, and I saw the three strange initial characters EF BB BF. I am guessing this is the Byte Order Marker.

This may seem trivial, but I am generating these automatically, and the recipient wishes to process them automatically, so this small issue is causing a problem.

Is there a way to do this without the BOM? Perhaps some altogether easier way to make the attachment?

This is my code:

```
  var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('message'),
    blob = Utilities.newBlob([]);
    blob.setDataFromString(csvdata, 'ASCII');
    blob.setContentType('text/csv');
    blob.setName('test.csv');
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: email,
      subject: 'Test',
      htmlBody: htmlBody,
      attachments: [blob]
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the extra characters you're seeing must be in the csvdata variable. I copied your code nearly exactly, but replaced csvdata with a hard-coded string, and it sent me an email with test.csv as an attachment with no preceding characters you describe.

If you run the function below directly through the script editor, does it work?

```
function test() {
   var htmlBody = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('message');
   var blob = Utilities.newBlob([]);
   blob.setDataFromString('hi there', 'ASCII');
   blob.setContentType('text/csv');
   blob.setName('test.csv');
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: 'YOUREMAIL@gmail.com',
     subject: 'Test',
     htmlBody: htmlBody,
     attachments: [blob]
   });
}
```